# How to write a test case which garbage collects in the middle of a function execution?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a native class:

```
class NativeClass
{
int someVariable;
public:
void someNativeFunction(){}
};
```

I have a managed class, which lightly wraps this native class.

```
class ManagedClass
{
NativeClass *nativeClassObject;
public:
void someManagedFunction()
{
    nativeClassObject->someNativeFunction();
}
};
```

I use this managed class in my C# application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
ManagedClass objManagedClass = new ManagedClass();
objManagedClass.someManagedFunction();//line_1
//At this point onwards objManagedClass still has a reference on the stack, but is not used again.
//So, GC can delete this object.
}
```

Since `objManagedClass` is not referenced after line_1, garbage collector is free to destroy the object, even if it is processing the internal native call. This will lead to destruction of `objManagedClass`, which will in turn destroy `*nativeClassObject`. This is only likely to happen if `someNativeFunction` is allocating a lot of memory or is taking a long time, but just to be sure, I must add a reference to `objManagedClass` later after the call.

```
class ManagedClass
{
NativeClass *nativeClassObject;
public:
void someManagedFunction()
{
    nativeClassObject->someNativeFunction();
...
...
System::GC::KeepAlive(this);
}
};
```

`KeepAlive()` call should prevent GC from destroying it. Is there any way I can test this scenario? Some test case I could write that would fail if I did not provide `KeepAlive()`, but would pass once I called it? Would `Thread.Sleep(5000)` call in between the managed function help?

Comment: Just force a collection with GC::Collect() + GC::WaitFor.  Test it in the Release build with Tools > Options > Debugging > General, "Suppress JIT optimization" unticked.  First do this with a static member function, you should then in fact see the ManagedClass object getting collected.  Tells you that everything is configured right.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. However, [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.waitforpendingfinalizers?view=netframework-4.8) shows, I'd need to use it after my managed call is done. But, I want the managed object to deliberately get garbage collected during execution. While objManagedClass.someManagedFunction(); is executing, I'd like objManagedClass to be garbage collected. This can happen, right?

Comment: It isn't very clear to me what the trouble might be.  Just be sure to put the GC::Collect call inside someManagedFunction().

Comment: void someManagedFunction()
{
    nativeClassObject->someNativeFunction();  GC::Collect();  GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}. GC::Collect is happening after the someNativeFunction() call. I want the object(this) to be destroyed while it is executing someNativeFunction(). Otherwise, I am able to get the result I desired from native and then the object is collected

Answer (score 1):

You can force garbage collection to start by calling `GC::Collect` and then wait until garbage collection is finished using `GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers`. This should allow you to test your scenarios.

Take a look at the example on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.waitforpendingfinalizers?view=netframework-4.8)